# When to use use MapReduce in Hbase?

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I want to understand MapReduce of Hbase from application point of view, Need some real use cases of it to better understand the efficient use case of writing these jobs.

If there is any link to document or examples that explains the real use cases, Please share.

Answer (score 1):

I can give some example based on my use cases. If you already store your data in hbase, you can write a java program, which scans a table and do something, then write the output to hbase or somewhere else. OR you can use mapreduce to do the same. The difference is, mapreduce will run where the data is and network traffic is used only for result data. We have hourly jobs to calculate sum and average of kpis and input data is huge but output data is tiny for this task. If i did not use mapreduce, i need to move one hour of data over network which is 18gb. But mapreduce output is only 1mb and i can write it to hbase or file or somewhere else.

Also mapreduce gives you parallel task execution ability, which you can have in java but why :)

Keep in mind that YARN creates map tasks according to your hbase table's split count. So if you need more map task, split your table.

If you already store your data in hadoop hdfs, you are lucky, a mapreduce reading from hdfs is much faster than reading from hbase. Also you can still write mapreduce output to hbase, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the usecases given 
1. [here](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/mapreduce.example.html). 
2. And a small reference [here](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html) - 30.Joins
3. May be an end to end example [here](http://sujee.net/2011/04/10/hbase-map-reduce-example/#.VWM5_9JViko)

In the end, it all depends on your understanding of each concept Map reduce, Hbase and use it as per your need in your project. The same task can be done with or without map reduce. Happy coding